# Is it possible to have multiple file() tags in one php document

Tags: php, file

Is it possible to have multiple file() tags in one php document?
I have a file in which I am reading data from another file using `file()` and I also have to delete the last line in another document which I am also using `file()` for but when I run the code it doesn't remove the last line in the other file. 
The code that I am using to delete the last line:

```
function trim_lines($path, $max) { 
  // Read the lines into an array
  $lines = file($path);
  // Setup counter for loop
  $counter = 0;
  while($counter < $max) {
    // array_pop removes the last element from an array
    array_pop($lines);
    // Increment the counter
    $counter++;
  }  // End loop
  // Write the trimmed lines to the file
  file_put_contents($path, implode('', $lines));
}
```

This code works without a problem in a separate file but in this file it doesn't seem to work.

---

**There is no point in me posting the whole php code because it's pretty long and this is just a general question that would have the same effect in any php file.**

Comment: Check what `$max` has - which may mean it isn't going into the `while()` loop.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or var_dumping your code?

Comment: $max - as long as $counter is smaller than $max it will keep executing the remove line command and when $counter is bigger than $max it will write the rest of the array into the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example this function has to either be above the `file()` tag or not directly under the it.